# Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS does not work with Radeon Generic PnP display

Tags: 12.04, installation, radeon, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavillion g6-1330se laptop with Intel i5 processor, 6GB RAM, Radeon Generic PnP display and Windows 7 Home basic version. I have downloaded Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS from the website and have extracted the .iso file on to an external DVD. However, upon trying to boot from DVD, I get a blank screen. Also, I tried installing Ubuntu using Windows installer - while the installation goes through successfully and during booting I get options to select Windows 7 or Ubuntu, upon selecting Ubuntu, I get a blank screen.... How can I resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with ATi Radeon 6750HD. When you get the option to boot into Ubuntu, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and quickly hold left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. Choose Ubuntu recovery mode. It will give you a set of options. Select *Resume normal boot* and you are good to go.

Comment: Do you have to do that each time you boot? Or, is there a setting you can choose that will make a permanent fix?